# How to keep data synchronized in ember using ember-apollo-client?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, graphql, apollo

I have an app built using `Ember` and [ember-apollo-client](https://github.com/bgentry/ember-apollo-client).

```hbs
// templates/collaborators.hbs

// opens an ember-bootstrap modal
{{#bs-button type="success" onClick=(action (mut createCollaborator) true)}}Create collaborator{{/bs-button}}
// submit button in modal triggers "createCollaborator" in controller    

{{#each model.collaborators as |collaborator|}}
    {{collaborator.firstName}} {{collaborator.lastName}}
{{/each}}
```

```js
// routes/collaborators.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { RouteQueryManager } from 'ember-apollo-client';
import query from '../gql/collaborators/queries/listing';

export default Route.extend(RouteQueryManager, {
    model() {
        return this.get('apollo').watchQuery({ query }); 
    }
});

// controllers/collaborator.js
export default Controller.extend({
  apollo: service(),

  actions: {
    createCollaborator() {
      let variables = { 
        firstName: this.firstName, 
        lastName: this.lastName, 
        hireDate: this.hireDate 
      }

      return this.get('apollo').mutate({ mutation, variables }, 'createCollaborator')
        .then(() => {
          this.set('firstName', '');
          this.set('lastName', '');
          this.set('hireDate', '');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Currently, after creating a collaborator the data is stale and needs a browser refresh in order to update. I'd like the changes to be visible on the collaborators list right away.

From what I understood, in order to use `GraphQL` with Ember, I should use either `Ember Data` with [ember-graphql-adapter](https://github.com/alphasights/ember-graphql-adapter) OR just `ember-apollo-client`. I went on with `apollo` because of its better documentation.

I dont think I quite understood how to do that. Should I somehow use the `store` combined with `watchQuery` from `apollo`? Or is it something else?

## **LATER EDIT**

**Adi** almost nailed it.

- `mutationResult` actually needs to be the mutation itself.
- second param in `store.writeQuery` should be either `data: { cachedData  }` or `data` as below.

Leaving this here as it might help others.

```
return this.get('apollo').mutate({
    mutation: createCollaborator,
    variables,
    update: (store, { data: { createCollaborator } }) => {
      const data = store.readQuery({ query })

      data.collaborators.push(createCollaborator);

      store.writeQuery({ query, data });
    }
  }, createCollaborator');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the apollo imperative store API similar to this:

```js
return this.get('apollo').mutate(
    { 
        mutation, 
        variables, 
        update: (store, { data: {mutationResult} }) => {
            const cachedData = store.readyQuery({query: allCollaborators})

            const newCollaborator = mutationResult; //this is the result of your mutation

            store.writeQuery({query: allCollaborators, cachedData.push(newCollaborator)})
        }
    }, 'createCollaborator')
```